# Execute adb commands from java

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, adb

I want to push a file from my Java program to an Android emulator. Now, I can launch the emulator by using ProcessBuilder and also trap the logcat messages. But whenever I'm trying to use the adb push command in process builder, the process hangs and no output is generated.

The code:

```
try {
    ProcessBuilder proc = new ProcessBuilder("D://android-sdk//platform-tools//adb.exe",
                                             "push D:\\final.xml /mnt/sdcard/final.xml");
    Process p = proc.start();
    BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    while ( (line = br2.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(line);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Error");
}
```

EDIT:-
Found the probabble solution. I was using Process.waitFor() method but not storing its returned exitcode. Now as i did this:

```
int exitVal = p.waitFor();
```

Everything worked as a charm.

And @Marc Van Daele
Thanks for your input. as per my experience,  ProcessBuilder works in both ways ie. You can use arguments separated by spaces or by commas. :)

Comment: To be honest, I think it's unlikely that storing the return value of waitFor solves the issue.  I rather think that, sometimes, you are fast enough to read the data out of the InputStream (and then it works OK) and sometimes you are not, and then you run into the 'hang' issue.

Comment: Yeah.. after I made the edit .. it felt kinda wierd to me too. But I am not facing the same issue for quite some time now.
Thanks for your help guyz :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shouldn't this be separate arguments like

```
ProcessBuilder proc = new ProcessBuilder("D://android-sdk//platform-tools//adb.exe", "push",  "D:\\final.xml", "/mnt/sdcard/final.xml");
```

Comment: you are reading the p.getInputStream()? I think you should read the OutputStream and the ErrorStream.  Probably, it's also a good idea to set proc.redirectErrorStream(true); and only read the OutputStream.  Probably you are running into "Because some native platforms only provide limited buffer size for standard input and output streams, failure to promptly write the input stream or read the output stream of the subprocess may cause the subprocess to block, and even deadlock." as described http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html

Comment: ignore my (incorrect) comment on input vs out stream above.  The remainder of my comment is valid though.

Comment: I actually made some experiments and this answer seems to be right.

Comment: Amazing ! great answer.. saved lots of time.. Thanks a lot!